# @RequestScopedをつけるとRuntime Exceptionになる。

Tags: java, java-ee, annotations

**【事象】**
画面から番号と氏名を入力し、その入力内容をコンソールに表示する、というプログラムを書いているのですが、実行すると、RuntimeExceptionになり、画面が開けません。

**【試したこと】**
バッキングビーン(MeiboBean.java)の@RequestScopedを削除して実行してみたら、画面を表示するところまではできました。なので、おそらく@RequestScopedアノテーションを書いたことが原因だと思うのですが、書き方が間違っているとは思えないです。
このサイトに書いてある、importを使わない方法は、試しましたが、それでもだめでした。

**【環境】**

- ブラウザ：IE
- 統合開発環境：NetBeans
- サーバランタイム：glassfish

**【ソースコード】**

```
package bean;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MeiboBean{
    private Integer number;
    private String name;

    public void toConsole(){
        System.out.println("number = "+this.number+ "/ name=" +this.name);
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Sample01</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2>名簿データの作成</h2>
        <h:form>
            番号：<h:inputText value="#{meiboBean.number}" /><br/>
            氏名：<h:inputText value="#{meiboBean.name}" /><br/>
            <h:commandButton value="送信"  actionListener = "#{meiboBean.toConsole()}"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>


java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at bean.MeiboBean.<init>(MeiboBean.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:676)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:147)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:92)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:126)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:175)
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/237560

Answer (score 0):

バージョンはいくつですか？
古い版だと動きましたが、新しい版だと動作が不安定でした。

OK case)
NetBeans 8.02(Java EE7)
JDK 1.7
JSF 2.2
Glassfish 4.1

NG case)  同様に上から
12(EE7 or EE8)
JDK 1.7 , 1.8 , 11
JSF 2.2, 2.3
Glassfish 5.1

※ちなみに、RequestScopeを書かなければ、bean(CDI)と連携できません。
これはページ表示時にInjectionするとき、インスタンス生成が失敗しているというメッセージです。

Comment: こちらを参照。[stackoverflow.com/q/57127247](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57127247).

またこちらも
[stackoverflow.com/q/64056394/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64056394) 
nb-javac プラグインを入れることで解決できました。